# A not Euclidean PID by prof. Wilson

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}$ and let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. I have to prove that $R$ is a PID. To prove this fact, let I be an ideal of R and choose a non-zero $b \in I$ such that its complex norm $|b|$ is the least possible. Then let $a \in I \setminus\{b\}$. I have to prove that there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ such that $|ap−bq|<|b|$.
Since we may replace $a$ by any element $a'=a−bq$, we may subtract any desired element of $R$ from $\frac{a}{b}$.

1) In particular, we can assume that the imaginary part $y$ of $\frac{a}{b}=x+iy$ lies in $[-\frac{\sqrt{-19}}{4};\frac{\sqrt{-19}}{4}]$. How can I obtain this particular interval? Can I choose another interval?

2) Now if the imaginary part of $\frac{a}{b}$ lies strictly between $\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ then $\frac{a}{b}$ lies at distance less than 1 from some ordinary integer, and we are done. Why I obtain the numbers $\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$? May I take another couple of particular numbers? Moreover, how can I proof that $\frac{a}{b}$ lies at distance less than 1 from some ordinary integer?

3) We may assume that the imaginary part of $\frac{a}{b}$ lies between $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{19}}{4}$ (or the negative of this, where the argument is the same). Hence the imaginary part of $\frac{2a}{b}-\omega$ lies between $\sqrt{3}-\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}$.
Being $\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}-\sqrt{3}>0$, the imaginary part of $\frac{2a}{b}-\omega$ is sufficiently small that the complex number lies at a distance less than 1 from some ordinary integer. Why this imaginary part is small so that $\frac{2a}{b}-\omega$ has distance less 1 from some ordinary integer?

Thus in both cases we have found elements $p,q \in R$ such that $|ap − bq| < |b|$ (in fact with $p = 1$ and $q=n \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $p = 2$ and $q=\omega$). This contradicts the assumption that $I \ne bR$.

Please, can you answer to the questions 1), 2) and 3)?

Comment: You asked this (partially) before and you've already an answer there. Try to understand that and *then* ask anything more. Too long and involved questions to ask them in the same psot.

Comment: I read your answer, but my problem is why we obtain $\frac{\sqrt{19}}{4}$ and not any other number. I want to write the calculations thanks to which we obtain that number. This is my problem.

Comment: It's not that we "obtain" that number, @federico. It is that with it and some estimmations things work out. Have you even read at all the whole article by Wilson?